# Explanation of Histogram between OpenCV and ImageJ

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram, imagej

I have opened an image in ImageJ and output a histogram representation of the loaded image. With ImageJ, i am able to access the list of pixel values corresponding to their occurrences in the image.

However, when i tried to load the image into a sample prototype written using OpenCV in order to compute its histogram with the list of pixel values as well as their frequency, i get a completely different result; yet, the plotting of both histogram output similar shape of distribution.

Histogram of OpenCV is calculated by:

```
cv::calcHist(
        &image,
        1,
        channels,
        cv::Mat(),
        hist,
        1,
        histSize,
        ranges
        );
```

and accessed by

`histo.at<float>(i)`

The results can be seen in snapshot below:

The Upper image is from OpenCV example while the second image is computed using ImageJ

[image: OpenCV]
[image: ImageJ]

This is because i am trying to extract the similar values as computed by ImageJ using OpenCV in C++. Thanks.

NOTE:Both have the same pixel counts

Comment: You mean that the pixel count = sum bin values  is the same for both programs? And which is the format of the image and its pixel type (8bit..32bit?)

Comment: hi, lib, in OpenCV, the bin is 256 but i am not sure in imageJ, the image is in 8bit greyscale in .png format

Comment: try to check if your problem is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/25181745/1136458

Comment: Hi lib, i have seen the links you referred, however, i dont think there is any thing wrong with the OpenCV histogram yet it is so different to the one in ImageJ. Thus, maybe, i suspect that the difference of interpretation of the pixel values corresponds to the histogram might be the cause. If only i can know the way of how ImageJ calculated the histogram.